# node.js mongodb only update first found subdocument in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

a User collection:

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("5785d10570d6c39923d476cf"),
"name" : "BB Cafe",
"transaction" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "m69bkn",
            "type" : "TYPE1",
            "amount" : 0,
        },
        {
            "id" : "nhaa94",
            "type" : "TYPE1",
            "amount" : 0,
        }
]

}
```

update statement

```
var mongodbObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

 db.collection('user').update(
        {_id:new mongodb.ObjectID("5785d10570d6c39923d476cf"), 
          "transaction.amount":0, 
          "transaction.type":"TYPE1", 
          "transaction.id":"nhaa94"
        }, {$set:{"transaction.$.amount":0.6}}, {w:1}, function(err, resultUpdate) {

}
```

It updated to `transaction.id = "m69bkn"` instead of `"nhaa94"`
It just update the first found subdocument I guess
I have been searching here in SO like

[update array with $ is not working in mongodb-native nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168864/update-array-with-is-not-working-in-mongodb-native-nodejs)

and

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

and

[Updating an array item using NodeJS, MongoDB & Monk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518416/updating-an-array-item-using-nodejs-mongodb-monk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a query like this using the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("5785d10570d6c39923d476cf"), 
   "transaction": {
      "$elemMatch": {     
        "amount": 0, 
        "type": "TYPE1", 
        "id": "nhaa94" 
   }
}
```

Comment: you are my hero !!